# Не работает второй/третий/... хендлер, а только первый

Tags: python, aiogram, telebot

Почему срабатывает только первый хендлер?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_messages(message: types.Message):
    # some code 1

@dp.message_handler(content_types="text")
async def get_messages2(message: types.Message):
    # some code 2

@dp.message_handler(text="some-text")
async def get_messages3(message: types.Message):
    # some code 3
```

Comment: Сделал этот вопрос чтобы можно было на него ссылаться в будущем, ибо такие вопросы надоели.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ подходит как для `aiogram` так и для `pytelegrambotapi(telebot)`.

Итак. Этот хендлер

```
@dp.message_handler()
```

имеет фильтры по-умолчанию `content_types="text"` и `state=None`(только Aiogram). Потому любые сообщения типа текст, будут в нём, и любой другой хендлер ниже не будет даже проверяться, так как происходит следующее.

Юзер отправляет сообщение или нажимает на инлайн кнопку, сообщение попадает в бот и проходит по всем хендлерам в порядке регистрации (то бишь первый регистрированный первым и провериться), и если фильтры подходят и выдают `True` то хендлер срабатывает и дальнейшие хендлеры игнорируются.

Чтобы не было таких казусов нужно хендлеры с пустыми фильтрами (или же таким же как и по-умолчанию) ставить в самый низ регистрации. По факту просто вырезать и вставить в конце кода.

К примеру чтобы код в вопросе работал нужно два первых хендлера слить в один и поставить ниже третьего.

```
@dp.message_handler(text="some-text")
async def get_messages3(message: types.Message):
    # some code 3

@dp.message_handler()
async def get_messages(message: types.Message):
    # some code 1/2
```

#### Полностью аналогичная ситуация и для колбек хендлеров.