# Telegrambot. Не выводит текст сообщения для пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю бота. Алгоритм работы следующий:

1. Открывается меню с выбором города в Московской области;
2. После того должно открываться меню с выбором района в этом городе (уменьшаем диапазон);
3. После выбора района - должно приходить сообщение с тарифами в том районе.
   Проблема в следующем - не могу заставить бота отправлять пользователю сообщение с текстом.

Как решить эту проблему?
Код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")

first = ["МОЕ = 2,5% Мособлгаз 2,3%"]
second = ["2"]
second_add = ["3"]
third = ["4"]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Балашиха')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Воскресенск')
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton('Дмитров')
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton('Домодедово')
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton('Химки')
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберете Ваш почтамт' .format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Балашиха':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Реутов')
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Николаев')
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton('Нижний')
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберете район', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Реутов':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('4')
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('5')
        back = types.KeyboardButton('6')
        markup.add(item1, item2, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Текст для примера!!!', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает второй/третий/... хендлер, а только первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463450/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9)

Comment: @oleksandrigo Спасибо Вам ответ. Да, вопрос и правда дублируется, но к сожалению я так и не понял как исправить. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну к примеру убери две строчки `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) def bot_message(message):`

Comment: @oleksandrigo просто удалить две эти строки?

Comment: Да, так и сделай

Comment: @oleksandrigo спасибо за совершенно не рабочее решение. Потратил только время...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен при помощи двух разных кнопок меню.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).