# После первого @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) код будто не виден и все значения присваиваются первому

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot, time
from telebot import types


token = '568893GkJIDsgSOkd-4w0IEsAw'
mess = {}
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Я телеграмм-бот, который умеет повышает активность на сайте. Что-бы начать со мной работать напиши url сайта.')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def url_message(message):
    url = message.text
    mess['url'] = url
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично! Теперь введи время выполнения задачи')
    print(mess)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def time_message(message):
    time = message.text
    mess['time'] = time
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось указать кол-во посещений сайта')
    print(mess)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])    
def visit_message(message):
    visit = message.text
    mess['visit'] = visit
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Всё! Задача выполняется! Теперь ожидай отклика программы ')
print(mess)
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает второй/третий/... хендлер, а только первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463450/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9)

Comment: Также советую глянуть это там я описал как сделать то что вы хотите [ссылка на тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478675/Почему-не-стоит-запихивать-хендлеры-внутрь-других-хендлеров)