# как сделать ответы на сообщения в телеграмм боты в python aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы телеграмм бот на python aiogram отвечал на мои сообщения через handler
то есть

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def answer(message : types.Message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "И тебе привет!!!")
```

я написал такой код и он работал, но когда я добавил еще один handler он уже не работал

```
@dp.message_handler() #это первый handler 
async def answer(message : types.Message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "И тебе привет!!!")

@dp.message_handler() 
async def answer(message : types.Message):
    if message.text == "Пока":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "До завтра")
```

И вот первый handler работает, а второй нет, все сообщения попадают в первый handler, и на все сообщения бот отвечает "Привет", а на "Пока" он отвечает. Как это исправить?

я пробовал исправить смотря документацию, но ничего не работает

Comment: Рекомендую к прочтению https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463450/Не-работает-второй-третий-хендлер-а-только-первый/1463451#1463451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хэндлере добавьте вот так:

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text.lower() == 'привет')
async def answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('и тебе привет')


@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text.lower() == 'пока')
async def answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('и тебе пока')


@dp.message_handler()
async def answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('...')
```

таким образом первые 2 хэндлера будут ловить `привет` и `пока`, а третий все то, что не отловилось первыми двумя

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: обратите внимание, что срабатывание происходит при точном совпадении сообщения, т.е. при `как дела` не произойдет срабатывания на сообщении `как дела?` . Можете изменить `lambda msg: msg.text.lower() == 'как дела'` на `lambda msg: 'как дела' in msg.text.lower()`

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев судя по вашему сообщению вы разобрались и данный вариант вас устраивает, в таком случае можете отметить мой ответ как решение, нажав на соответствующую кнопку слева от ответа